# Get the IndentLevel property of a cell in Excel without opening the file in Excel

Tags: excel, oledb, vba

Is it possible to retrieve the IndentLevel property of a cell in Excel without opening the file in Excel (using OleDB or an equivalent). If yes, how?  Thks.

Comment: Why is it necessary *not* to open the file? Reason I ask is because there are ways to open a file without making it look like the file is being opened and it's much easier to do it with an open file. (I doubt it can even be done with an unopen one, but I am not 100% familar with all commands that work against a closed workbook).

Comment: The time to open Excel and read the file is too long.  I am actually reading the file in Excel with Excel hidden (Application.Visible = False).  Once the file read, I save the information in a json file so it is faster to access the information after, but the firt-time opening of the Excel file is still too long.